# Civi Updating, 5.0

Tags: wordpress, upgrade

I tried to work on my database when I got a DB Error: no such field. I can't access my contacts at all. I can search for them, they appear and everything else works. I looked up the error and I found out that I should update civi. I followed the instructions from https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Upgrading+CiviCRM+for+Wordpress#UpgradingCiviCRMforWordPress-4.RuntheUpgradescript .

But after following all the steps and putting in the update URL I still get an error saying that I have already upgraded to version 4.7.17. I don't understand what is going on. Can anyone help? I know that the guide is for 4.7+ but I am not sure if that applies for 5.0 too.

Comment: Have you replaced the old civicrm codebase with the 5.0 version?

Comment: Codebase? I replaced the old civicrm folder with the 5.0 version if that is what you mean.

Comment: Did you completely remote the old civicrm folder before putting 5.0 in, or did you copy the new files on top of the old ones?

Comment: I completely removed the old files and then put 5.0 in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently the people before me who was using the website had the files on another server and gave me a different server credentials. Thank you all who took the time to try and help I am sorry for the weird question.

Comment: You should be able to Accept your own answer to help close this